# extern "C" in framework .h works in a project but not works in other

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I am facing some weird issue in XCode workspace. I neither have much experience in Objective-C nor in C/C++. I mostly work with Unity3D/C#.

Nowadays I am trying to create few native plugins for the iOS game, for the same I have created few `Cocoa touch Framework` in a single Xcode workspace, let's say I have four projects in the workspace.

- Project A
- Project B
- Project C
- Project D

All project have the same project config (like Deployment Target, Architecture, Base OS etc.)

Now Project A is a common framework which used by other 3 projects few common tasks like
- Communicate back with unity
- Getting C string from NSString and vice-versa
- Create JSON data string from NSObject or NSDictionary

Those all methods are written with `Objective-C` in  `.mm` file. the same file also has written `C` bridge code to access via other-custom-framework/Unity-code via `extern "C".

The `.h` file has a declaration of the same methods of `Objective-C` in the proper interface and `C` in `extern C`.

This setup works perfectly without any issue/error in Project B, Project C, Project D.

The issue only comes with `extern "C"` with new "Cocoa Touch framework" Project "Project E" created today.

When I try to build project E throw error in Project A's header file in line where `extern "C"`.

`error: expected identifier or '(' extern "C" {`

When I try to build any other 3 projects It's work fine without any issue. and work perfectly as frameworks in Unity based iOS games.

I tried to match build setting of Project E with other projects but I can't find any changes.

So I have stuck in this weird issue. I also searched on Google for the same. Most posts indicate to use #ifdef __cpluscplus

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
// Method Declaration
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

this solves the issue on Project E, but still, I don't get actual issue why the only error in Project E and not in other Projects.

Please guide me for the same.

Comment: `extern "C" {` only makes sense in a `.cpp` file. If you inlcude the header without the `#ifdef __cplusplus` in a `.c` file, then it will throw an error.

Comment: @paul-ogilvie, Thanks for your comment and your point. 

But I am still confused about why only when I use the framework in a particular project, Neither it throws an error when I build/compile framework it-self nor in another project where I use the same framework. I am not an expert in C/C++/Objective-C, but I think it's some issue with either XCode project configuration or build configuration.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. A `.cpp` file is considered C++ and a `.c` file is considered C, so different compilers process the files. So if you include `extern C` in a `.c` file, the C compiler will complain, and if you include `extern C` in a `.cpp` file, the C++ compiler accepts it. So check your file extensions, which imply a C or C++ compiler.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thanks, Sir, I found the same as per your last comment, the issue only occurred with the file has extension .m (maybe that file represents C/Objective-C code and `extern "C"` throw error) while .mm files represent C++/Objective-C++ code) Now I am working on the same the separate functions to call one from another